# How to use any cpu platform dll for 32 bit application in vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am using one dll that is build for any cpu platform and I am developing an application for x86 platform as I am taking reference of this dll in my application i am unable to access class of it.

Can you please suggest me what should I do?

I just want to use that "any cpu" platform build dll in my application of x86 platform or 32 bit application.

Comment: Your title says you want to use it for a 64 bit application but your question states you want it for the x86 platform?

Comment: x86 will mean that it is intended to run only as a 32 bit process

Comment: There's no exception that says "i am unable to access class of it".  You need to quote the exact message.  A stack trace never hurts either.

Comment: @HansPassant Passant error message is **"Type 'xyz' is not defined."** that means i am unable to access that dll or class.

Comment: @AlokChandraShahi - All that error means is that you have not added the required reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem to use the DLL anyway if the DLL is really built for "any CPU". 
You could use the coreflags utility though to change the settings of the assembly to match your target platform.

Comment: but after taking reference of that dll i am unable to use class of it. don't know why ?

Comment: Have you checked what you see when using the object catalog after double-clicking on the reference part of your solution?